# org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ParserInitializationException: Unknown parser type: Linux

Tags: java, linux, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to connect to FTP server which is on Linux, I am getting below exception when I execute `ftp.listFiles(remote);`

```
SYST 215  Linux  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ParserInitializationException:
Unknown parser type:  Linux     at
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:165)
at
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:94)
at
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3192)
at
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2857)
```

The same code is working fine when I connect to FTP server which is on Windows.

I searched for the solution of it but I guess no one has faced such issue with linux. Found one post here which recommends to use `listNames()` instead `listfiles()` but that too is not working with different error.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient()    
ftp.configure(new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX));
```

Try setting an [FTPCientConfig](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClientConfig.html) that matches your system.