# Apache vfs: Unknown parser type: UNKNOWN XFB/Gateway

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

This is my first question on Stackoverflow after being developing in Java for a few years, generally I find other Q&A's very helpfull, but for this problem I haven't found a solution yet, though I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009094/org-apache-commons-net-ftp-parser-parserinitializationexception-unknown-parser) :

In my case, I'm trying to connect to a Windows NT server with LS file listing that runs a WRQ Reflection ftp server (which they say does not run in sftp mode, but accepts regular ftp-connections).
But it fails: UNKNOWN XFB/Gateway

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ParserInitializationException: Unknown parser type: UNKNOWN XFB/Gateway
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2263)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2046)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2093)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:137)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:113)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:138)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildFile(FtpFileObject.java:111)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getInfo(FtpFileObject.java:196)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetType(FtpFileObject.java:319)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:441)
... 66 more
```

I am not sure wether which one of the available parsers would work (The UNIX one because of the LS file listing?) and if neither would suffice, where to begin to implement my own parser.

The problem is that I can't test the connection myself. Our Java-application runs in a client's domain that tries to connect to a 3rd party that only accepts incoming connections from the clients domain and at the moment they are not really helpfull (at least not in allowing me to connect to their ftp-server from outside the client's domain).

And just committing a change + building a new release (& let our client test it) based on a hunch is something I rather not do just now.

Our code always worked fine with other ftp-servers our client used our program with to export files, but this is a new connection they set up.

So in short:

- 1a. Which of the standard apache-commons EntryParsers is likely to be able to work with the 3rd party's ftp-server
- 1b. If neither would suffice, what information do I need to implement our own EntryParser (looks rather complex for a FTP-n00b like me)?
- 2. Can anyone give me a pointer on how to set up a suitable free test-ftp server locally which uses the XFB Gateway protocol? My company doesn't like me installing evaluation-editions of potential expensive enterprise solutions, like WRQ Reflection